# Cucumber Report doubles the execution time then shown Karate HTML Report

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am generating Cucumber reports after execution of tests in karate by passing json file generated by using below code

```
  String folderpath = null;
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String currentDateTime = dtf.format(now);
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    folderpath = currentDir + "/reports/"+"TestExecution"+currentDateTime;


    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    final List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));

    File file = new File(folderpath);
    file.mkdirs();

    Configuration config = new Configuration(file, "IPAY");
    config.addClassifications("Platform", "Windows");
    config.addClassifications("Browser", "chrome");
    config.addClassifications("ENV", "SIT");

    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
```

However the reports are showing different execution time: Karate reports

[image]

Cucumber reports generated:

[image]

As it can be seen that in cucumber reports time is almost doubled as we can see in karate report. Also same behavior observed when executed in parallel. We are publishing cucumber reports, So Is it possible to resolve this issue ?

Comment: this has never been reported before. so please follow this process. may I recommend that you contribute code also if needed: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue